# How to assign an array element which can be null in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

In my Swift app, I'm querying an api returning a json object like this :

```
{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    array : [
        {
            id: 1,
            string: "foobar"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            string: "foobar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Facts :

- The array value can be empty.
- I want to read the first array element,
  present or not.

In Swift i'm doing :

```
  if let myArray: NSArray = data["array"] as? NSArray {
      if let element: NSDictionary = myArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
          if let string: NSString = element["string"] as? NSString {
              // i should finally be able to do smth here,
              // after all this crazy ifs wrapping
          }
      }
  }
```

It works if the array and the first element exist, but i'm having a crash with "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array" even if the element assignment is within an if let wrapping.

What i am doing wrong here ? I'm getting crazy with Swift optionals, typing and crazy if let wrapping everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not concerning about `Optional`. If you use subscription(`[]`) for array, you have to check the length of that.

```
if let myArray: NSArray = data["array"] as? NSArray {
    if myArray.count > 0 { // <- HERE
        if let element: NSDictionary = myArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
            if let string: NSString = element["string"] as? NSString {
                println(string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But we have handy [`.firstObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/firstObject) property

> The first object in the array. (read-only)
>
> If the array is empty, returns nil.

Using this:

```
if let myArray: NSArray = data["array"] as? NSArray {
    if let element: NSDictionary = myArray.firstObject as? NSDictionary {
        if let string: NSString = element["string"] as? NSString {
            println(string)
        }
    }
}
```

And, we can use ["Optional Chaining"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) syntax:

```
if let str = (data["array"]?.firstObject)?["string"] as? NSString {
    println(str)
}
```

Comment: I was having difficulties to understand all of that. This answer is well detailed and clear. Thanks, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
var a = [Any?]()
a.append(nil)
```

If you have a non-optional array with `AnyObject` you can use `NSNull` (like in Obj-C)